# Nginx wont install due to being unable to make backup link

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vagrant

I am attempting to simply install nginx on a raw ubuntu box.  I using vagrant and issuing ''vagrant up'' to ubuntu/trusty64 and then attempting to install nginx.  It is giving this error:
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/share/nginx/html/index.html' before installing new version: Operation not pe

This is the full output:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libgd3 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libtiff5 libvpx1 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 nginx-common
  nginx-core
Suggested packages:
  libgd-tools fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libgd3 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libtiff5 libvpx1 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 nginx
  nginx-common nginx-core
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,704 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,056 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-dejavu-core.
(Reading database ... 59966 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-dejavu-core_2.34-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-dejavu-core (2.34-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fontconfig-config.
Preparing to unpack .../fontconfig-config_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fontconfig-config (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfontconfig1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfontconfig1_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfontconfig1:amd64 (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg-turbo8_1.3.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 (1.3.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjpeg8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg8:amd64 (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjbig0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libjbig0_2.0-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjbig0:amd64 (2.0-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtiff5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtiff5_4.0.3-7ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtiff5:amd64 (4.0.3-7ubuntu0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvpx1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libvpx1_1.3.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvpx1:amd64 (1.3.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxpm4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxpm4_1%3a3.5.10-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxpm4:amd64 (1:3.5.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgd3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgd3_2.1.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgd3:amd64 (2.1.0-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxslt1.1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxslt1.1_1.1.28-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.28-2build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/share/nginx/html/index.html' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-core.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-core_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-core (1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue...
The key is this line in the error -

`unable to make backup link of './usr/share/nginx/html/index.html'`

You probably set your Vagrant share dir to be in `/usr/share/nginx/html` and there are likely files in there? Vagrant sets up the share dir before anything else, and it is done as root. The installer is likely having issues backing up this content due to permissions issues.

I fixed it by:

1. shut down vagrant
2. comment out the share dir line in the Vagrant file
3. restart Vagrant
4. install nginx
5. shut down Vagrant
6. un-comment the share line in the Vagrant file
7. restart Vagrant